# angular bootstrap calendar not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the **angular bootstrap calendar** in my apache cordova app

**HTML:**

```
            <ion-view>
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true" ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="calendarController">
                    {{test}}
                    <mwl-calendar view="calendarView"
                      current-day="calendarDay"
                      events="events">
                </mwl-calendar>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('calendarController', ['$scope', '$state', 'moment', function ($scope, $state, moment) {

$scope.test = 'Test the controller';
$scope.calendarView = 'week';
$scope.calendarDay = new Date();
$scope.events = [
 {
     title: 'My event title', // The title of the event
     type: 'info',
     startsAt: new Date(2013, 5, 1, 1),
     endsAt: new Date(2014, 8, 26, 15),
     editable: false,
     deletable: false,
     incrementsBadgeTotal: true
 }
];
}]);
```

I have included the links to the relevant dependencies including `moment.js` however I get a message 'the value passed to current day attribute is not set'. I have made sure `moment.js` is linked before the main `app.js` file which contains the controller as suggested in a similar question but I still get the same message. I am new to angular and would appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

Comment: do you get anything from console.log? the calendar may show that message if there's some other error as well (e.g. I once got it when I had mistyped y.map(f) as map(f,y))

Comment: I am getting a similar error/warning that goes away after about a 1 second delay. Mine seems to be related to some variables not being set due to time lag in querying the API.

Comment: Is that fixed is some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using angular boostrap calendar, you need to know that some attribute are mandatory.

I don't see any **view-date** attribute define in your html file. Instead of

```
 current-day="calendarDay"
```

try:

```
 view-date="calendarDay"
```

You can check the README file of the official project for more details.